# C# Regex.Matches - Previous matched characters can not be matched in the next matches

Tags: c#, regex

I got the following regex call -

`MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(text,@"( And )|( Or )|( Not )"`

I got a problem with a string like this - " And Or Not "

Only "And" will be matched but "Or" and "Not" will not be, just because they are not the first word.

The reason as far as I understand is because the first match is " And " **including** the trailing white space, because of that the Regex does not recognize it as a potential white space for the next match, and ignores it, just because it was part of the first match.

So if for example this was my string instead - " And  Or  Not " - every word would have been matched.

Is there a way to somehow instruct the Regex to share the matched white-spaces between the matches?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of looking explicitly for whitespace, you should look for word boundaries.

Just had to go [look it up](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#character_classes), but apparently, `\b` would be what you're looking for, e.g.:

```
@"(\bAnd\b)|(\bOr\b)|(\bNot\b)"
```

(Or, as @stema points out):

```
@"\b(And|Or|Not)\b"
```

Comment: But you can simplifiy it a bit, by taking the word boundaries out of the brackets: `@"\b(And|Or|Not)\b"`

Comment: Also, I would suggest to use software like "The regulator" to quickly test your regexes.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, if you have matched a whitespace, the regex is continuing after the last match, the withespace is so to say "gone", because it has already been matched.

What you can do is to use a lookahead, like this:

```
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(s, @" (?:And|Or|Not)(?= )");
```

The lookahead is not matching the space, it is just looking ahead, if there is a space following. The expression will not match, if there is no space.
But the result in your MatchCollection will not have this space at the end!

Comment: +1 for mentioning lookahead, which is the more generic solution to this kind of problem

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the expression a little and use a [look-ahead assertion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah%28v=VS.100%29.aspx#zerowidth_positive_lookahead_assertion) (match something but don't make it part of the capture):

```
string text = " And Or Not ";
foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(text, @"\s(And|Or|Not)(?=\s)")) {
    Console.WriteLine(m.Value);
}
```

(note: I'm using `\s` instead of spaces)

Comment: Thanks, but it still not good enough. For some reason in this string - " And Or Not" only "And" and "Not are matched. For some reason Or is not getting matched, unless I'd add another white space before it. P.S: What does ?: stands for?

Comment: @Dror, sorry, see edited answer. And by the way: this works, but probably what you really need is Damien's answer.